# How can I dynamically set the time period on a Workflow Time Trigger?

Tags: time, triggers, workflow, salesforce

I have a custom object with Start and End date fields, and also a Status field.

When a new record is created, if the Start date specified is in the future, I would like to be able to have a Workflow update the Status field to 'Active' when the Start date is today.  However, I only appear to be able to select a fixed number of days after which my Field Update task can be triggered.  What I want is to set that number of days equal to Start date - Today's date.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I realised I can set the time delay to zero days after the Start date.  Not intuitive (For me), but it makes sense.